# View Controller behaves differently when set as 'initial view controller' vs. loading with presentModalViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

My app has a map that tracks the user's location. This map will only appear under certain circumstances, and will dominate the user's attention until a particular task is complete, which is why the map isn't part of a navigation or tab bar UI.

If my map VC is set as the initial view controller in storyboard, it works fine. But if I try to load the map VC from elsewhere like this;

```
MapViewController *mapVC = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:mapVC animated:YES];
```

I just get a black screen.

I can confirm with NSLog that the VC is calling viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear, but the 'map' property of the VC is (null). I don't understand why (or how) I need to create the map property manually when using this technique, but it gets done for me when it is the initial VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MapViewController instance in your storyboard is configured with a view hierarchy, including an MKMapView, and whatever else you did to configure **that particular instance** in the storyboard.

Now in this code which you show here, you are creating a completely new instance of MapViewController. It has no relationship to the instance in the storyboard other than they happen to be of the same class. So the one you create here with `[[MapViewController alloc] init]` has no view hierarchy (which is why you see a black screen), and none of the outlets or other configuration you may have made to the *other* MapViewController in your storyboard.

So what you want is to load that MapViewController that you've already set up from the storyboard. Assuming you are doing this from within a method in another view controller *loaded from the same storyboard already*, you can just do this:

```
// within some method on another vc from a scene in the same storyboard:

// given an identifier for the map view controller we want to load:
static NSString *mapVCIdentifier = @"SomeAppropriateIdentifier";

NSLog(@"Storyboard: %@",self.storyboard); // make sure this vc(self) was loaded from a storyboard
MapViewController *mapVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:mapVCIdentifier];
[self presentModalViewController:mapVC animated:YES];
```

And then back in the storyboard, just make sure you set the identifier for this map view controller to "SomeAppropriateIdentifier".

Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Many thanks to you for your detailed response. I'll be sure to take the time to understand it properly.

Comment: Glad that helped. Good luck with the app.